# How to use a For loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I’m quite new to R and have been working on the following code. I want the output of the first code to be used in the second code and so on. Is there an easy way to do this using a forloop or something?

```
Output1<- str_c(final, sorted)
Output2<- str_c(final, output1)
Output3<- str_c(final, output3)
```

Comment: `for (i in 1:3) sorted <- str_c(final, sorted)` now check what `sorted` is and compare it to your output 3

Comment: @onyambu i cant believe it was as simple as this! Thank you SO MUCH! 